# I want to make a timer for a screen after timeout it back to previous page

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to make a question app in flutter.in this app there is a section where in a button when button clicked it go to question screen also a timer will start after time out it back to previous page.it will be able for all button question.

i will try many way bt i can't solve this problem please help me

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you;ve tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full Code**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Help with a meal....';
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: const Page1(),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page1({super.key});

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Go to Page2"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page2({super.key});

  @override
  State<Page2> createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  late Timer timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page1()));
      print("changedpage");
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Go to Page1"),
            onPressed: () {
              timer.cancel();
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page1()));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: How can I get back without showing button

Comment: the button is to cancel the timer in case the user has selected the answer and navigate to the page before the timer runs out